# How can I look up each character in each line in a file as a variable name?

Tags: bash, loops, variables

in a bash script I have some variables set like this

```
A=1
B=2
```

I have a text file called list.txt that contains

```
AAB
ABA
BBA
```

also in my script I have

```
while read LINE
do
    echo "$LINE" | grep -o .
    echo "----"
done < list.txt
```

my output is

```
A
A
B
----
A
B
A
----
B
B
A
----
```

how would I go about getting this as my output?

```
112
----
121
----
221
----
```

Comment: BTW, this is not really ideal as a question -- if you narrowed its scope to only be asking one thing at a time, we'd have a duplicate already in the knowledge for just about anything that "one thing" could be. How to iterate over a line character-by-character, for instance, we've already got; how to look up a variable name to the value that variable has, we've already got; how to read a file or stream line-by-line, we've already got... etc.

Comment: Can you do something like `tr 'AB' $(echo "$A$B") < list.txt`, skipping the intermediate lines (that you can add with `| sed 's/$/\n----/`) ? How do you know which variables need to be used for the replaces?

Comment: @WalterA, ...of course, the above assumes that the replacement values can only be one character each.

Answer (score 1):

```
A=1
B=2
while IFS= read -r line; do
  for ((idx=0; idx < ${#line}; idx++)); do
    char=${line:$idx:1}
    val=${!char}
    printf '%s' "$val"
  done
  printf '%s\n' '' ----
done <<<$'AAB\nABA\nBBA'
```

...properly emits as output:

```
112
----
121
----
221
----
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative **bash** + **awk** solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

A=1
B=2
awk -v A="$A" -v B="$B" 'BEGIN{ keys["A"]=A; keys["B"]=B }
       { len=split($0,a,"");
       for (i=1;i<=len;i++) printf "%s%s", keys[a[i]], (i==len? "\n---\n":"") }' list.txt
```

---

The output:

```
112
---
121
---
221
---
```

---

But the **shortest** approach (without variables) would be with GNU **sed**:

```
sed 'y/AB/12/; s/$/\n---/' list.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how fixed your var's are.
(and always postprocess with `| sed 's/$/\n----/`)
A=1 and B=2 (always)

```
tr 'AB' '12' < list.txt
```

Only var's A and B, both 1 character long value.

```
tr 'AB' $(echo "$A$B") < list.txt
```

Only var's A and B, values can be longer

```
sed "s/A/$A/g; s/B/$B/g" list.txt
```

Var's exist for every letter in the inputfile - See @CharlesDuffy

Or perhaps you have a small set of var's

```
A=1;B=2;C=3;D=4;E=5;F=6; export A B D C E F
export I="(this is letter i)"
echo "CRAZY SED SOLUTION" | sed -r 's/[A-FI]/${&}/g' | envsubst
# Result
3R1ZY S54 SOLUT(this is letter i)ON
```